# Matlab: number of suplots based on a string with dimensions specified

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I need to decide how many subplots I need and their sizes and all the information is stored in a string.

Let's say there are four subplots and their sizes are:

Top: 1x1
Next: 2x1
Next: 2x1
Bottom: 1x1

Basically the middle two are two combined pairs.  Normally, I would specify the subplots as follows:

```
subplot(6,1,1)
subplot(6,1,[2:3])
subplot(6,1,[4:5])
subplot(6,1,6)
```

Now, this information is stored in a string as shown below:

```
'1;[2:3];[4:5];6'
```

So, the question is what is the most efficient way of getting the axes information from such string.

I can, of course, check each character in a string whether it's `','`,`';'`,`'['`,`':'`, or `']'`.  This will require for-looping to `length(str)` and many if statements, paring `'['`,`':'`,`']'`, asking 'is the character numeric?', 'is it colon, then?', etc.  This is very tedious.

I have tens of figures with such subplots and I can only think that there's got to be a better way of doing this.

Comment: Son, you got yourself a parsing problem.  No easy way around it, you got to parse yourself some strings.  Writing a parser ain't too hard for us old folks.  You youngin's probably never read the dragon book, so best of luck to you.  Flex and Yacc seem like over kill for your problem.  You most likely can get what you want out of strsplit and a parsel of if statements.

Comment: How about using `strsplit` to extract the plot indices i.e. `1`, `[2:3]`, `[4:5]`, `6`?

Comment: Magic!!!  strsplit is exactly what I want.  How do I select yours as an answer?  If you post your answer instead of a reply, I'll select it as the answer.

Comment: Eric, I suggest pinging @ParagS.Chandakkar as I just did so they get a notification. Can you avoid `eval` after `strsplit`? That would be best. Anyway: where does this string come from? Can't you avoid creating it, creating a cell the first place?

Comment: @AndrasDeak I understand why would one want to avoid calling `eval`. Could you elaborate on why you should avoid `strsplit`? I found a lot of articles advising against using `eval`, including [this](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/string-evaluation.html#bs7kmd5) from The Mathworks. However, nothing for `strsplit`. Interestingly, now I observed, that you have used `eval` in your answer.

Comment: @Eric I did not write that as an answer because it would have been just a one-liner. You needed something to separate `subplot` arguments from your string. So I thought of `strsplit` and it turned out to be correct. Why don't you write an answer for reference? :)

Comment: @ParagS.Chandakkar I don't think a one-liner answer is worth any less than a long answer, if it's enough:) And `strsplit` is perfect! I was just wondering whether you could avoid `eval` after `strsplit`: you'd end up with strings like `'[2:3]'`, which would still have to be converted to numeric arrays. If I could come up with an `eval`less answer, I would have given that. If you give an `eval`less answer, I'll gladly delete mine, as it's questionable practice at best.

Comment: @AndrasDeak Oh. I misunderstood, my apologies. I read it as, "Can you avoid eval and strsplit?". I did not write an answer because I had not thought of complete solution. I just stated `strsplit` and the let the OP figure out.

Comment: @Eric Check out my answer which doesn't use `eval`. If it works for you, please accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the string is stored in `str`

```
str='1;[2:3];[4:5];6'
splits=strsplit(str,';');
splits=cellfun(@str2num,splits,'uni',0);
for i=1:numel(splits)
    subplot(numel(splits),1,splits{i});
    %plot
end
```

Comment: Ooooh, I had no idea that `str2num` could parse through matlab's vector syntax:) Perfect, thanks! This is *the* right way to do this.

Comment: what does it mean by parsing?  I'd like to learn.  I do see str2num behaves different than str2double

Comment: @Eric I suggest next time adding my name with a "@" prepended to notify me of your comment (this is called "pinging" a user, which I just did with you). By "*parsing through matlab's vector syntax*" I simply meant that if you give it `v=str2num('4:6');` it will evaluate it as `v=4:6;`, which I didn't realize. I assumed that it could only convert literal numeric values, but instead it's much more apt. For instance, you can use `M=str2num('[2 4; 3 6]');` to define a matrix (which is pretty cool).

Comment: @AndrasDeak I see.  I always wondered why people use @ in front of names.  Thank you for the information and thank you for the answer.